# Spawn process asynchronously and display multiline output a line at a time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process, .net-6.0

I am running an IPerf3 command asynchronously from my c# application (.net6) and would like to display the response messages live, a line at a time.

I run the code below and this performs the task as required except the entire program appears after the command has complete, rather than during.

When run from the command line, a line of output appears once a second, so I would like to also achieve this in my program.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

bool complete = false;
int count = 0;
var proc = new Process
{
    EnableRaisingEvents = true,

    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "iperf3.exe",
        Arguments = $"-c 1.2.3.4",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
    }
};

proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Data); count++; };
proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

proc.Exited += (sender, args) =>
{
    complete = true;
};

proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();
proc.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine($"LineCount:{count}");
```

When executed, the program output is

```
Connecting to host 1.2.3.4, port 5201

[  4] local 1.2.1.1 port 52648 connected to 1.2.3.4 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  81.8 MBytes   685 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  88.2 MBytes   739 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  89.5 MBytes   752 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  90.0 MBytes   755 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  89.1 MBytes   748 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  90.0 MBytes   754 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  89.4 MBytes   750 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  85.5 MBytes   717 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  88.4 MBytes   742 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  89.9 MBytes   754 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   882 MBytes   740 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   882 MBytes   740 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.

LineCount:20
```

The count value of 20 implies that the command output is definitely being received a line at a time, so there is no issue relating to processing CR/LF.

The OutputDataReceived handler does not get called until after around 10s when the command has complete. I would like OutputDataReceived to be called once a second during command execution.

UPDATE:
It transpires that this particular application iperf3 does not flush the program output on a carriage return and provides (some versions) a --forceflush option to do so.

Comment: Have you tried `await proc.WaitForExitAsync();`?

Comment: What is the type of the application? Win Forms? WPF?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I tried WaitForWxitAsync(), but this made no difference. The code above is a console app - for testing.

Comment: @user5265160 `WaitForExitAsync` wouldn't make any difference because new processes already run ... in a different process. What does that other process generate? As [the docs show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=net-7.0#system-diagnostics-process-outputdatareceived) the events are fired for every line, not every character. If you want to redirect the stream output, use the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` StreamReaders

Comment: What is the final output like?

Comment: If that other process never sends a CR or LF character, the events will only be fired when the other process ends

Comment: The child process probably has buffering turned on, which is why the data doesn't reach the stream the parent is trying to read.  This is the problem that pseudo-ttys (rather than pipes) solve.